# C Signal Handler professor example explanation

Tags: c, pid, qnx

My QNX class notes has this example, I cant seem to figure out how my prof came up with that output. Can anyone explain this to me thoroughly?

When this program runs the parent process has a PID of 1234 and the child process has 5678.

Output
5678: counter = 0
1234: counter = 10

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

/*
 * getpid() - returns the current processes pid.
 * getppid() - returns the parent processes pid.
 */

int counter = 0;

void signal_handler(int signo)
{
    counter++;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int rv;

    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    //queue signals.
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);

    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);

    switch(fork())
    {
        case 0:
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
            }
            break;
        default:
            wait(&rv);
            break;
    }

    printf("%d: counter = %d\n", getpid(), counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So.. have you run it yourself?

Comment: @EugeneSh.i did

Comment: What do you think it will do? Why?

Comment: @rici i cant figure out why the output is a 0 first and then a 10

Comment: @bob: how does the child's counter get incremented? How does the parent's?

Comment: Or is your question "why does the child report before the parent?" (Although that's pretty obvious given the semantics of `wait` :-) )

Comment: @rici when the counter is 0, does the kill function execute?

Comment: What does the counter have to do with the `kill`? Do you understand how `fork()` works and what it returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fork` creates a child process with its own copy of `counter`.

The `kill`, called by the child process, is sending a `SIGUSR1` to the parent process because it is using `getppid()` to get the pid.

The parent process is either blocked in the `wait`, or somewhere between the `fork` and the `wait`.  For each `SIGUSR1` sent by the child, the parent will jump into the signal handler, increment its copy of `counter`, and return to whatever it was doing.

In general, `wait` can return with an `EINTR` error if a signal is handled while it is waiting.  Setting `SA_RESTART` in `sa.sa_flags` ensures that system call will be restarted, but here it assumes that the `wait` will not be interrupted by the signal (does QNX guarantee this?).

The child's copy of `counter` is not affected.  The `wait` causes the parent to block until the child has exited.  The child thus prints its value of `counter`, which is `0`, and exits, the parent wakes from the `wait` and prints its value of `counter`, which is `10`.